# 301 redirect from example.com to example.com/ by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is there any way for redirecting domain to domain with slash?

`example.com` to `example.com/`

Comment: you want to redirect in all cases or only for some special case?

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\index.php$ / [L]

Comment: if user enter to site.com, I want redirect him to site.com/

Comment: `site.com` is same as `site.com/`

Comment: Your question is not clear. An URL has a path. If you enter `http://www.example.com` (so without any path) the browser will automatically understand it is `http://www.example.com/` and hence query for the `/` path. So what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 - Redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Example 2 - Redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

More information is [Here](https://secure.hostmetro.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?vis_module=selfhelp&vis_operation=view_article&vis_article_id=52)